# Topological sense in sphere with whisker & sphere with ingrown whisker

Tags: general-topology

Let $S^2$ be the standard $2$-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Let

$$A= S^2 \cup \{(0,0,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | 1 \le z \le 2 \}$$ the sphere with a whisker and let $$B= S^2 \cup \{(0,0,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | 0 \le z \le 1 \}$$ be the sphere with an ingrown whisker.

(a) In what topological sense are $A$ and $B$ the same ?

(b) In what topological sense are $A$ and $B$ different ?

(c) Consider $A$ and $B$ as embebedded in the three dimensional slice of $\mathbb {R}^4$ consisting all points whose fourth coordinates equal zero. Describe an ambient isotopy of $\mathbb {R}^4$that deforms $A$ into $B$.

I try to solve question from this [book](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=Nn4s88rjNSsC&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=sphere%20with%20whisker%20on%20topology&source=bl&ots=bD9fFQYmWu&sig=AS6wvDR8AWnHXFQohDHGyfS0mXo&hl=id&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrwZbHiovUAhXBnpQKHQ73AEMQ6AEINzAG#v=onepage&q=sphere%20with%20whisker%20on%20topology&f=false) on page 37 until 40 and I stack to do some question one of them is number 10, anyone can help me to solve this question ?

Comment: Well, what exactly are you struggling with? You should state in your question what you have tried/where you are getting stuck.  A lot of times, that will already help you help yourself ;) Maybe you're just new to a lot of definitions and have to understand them (better).

Comment: For a), think about homotopy, for b), I don't really know (maybe looking at the previous exercises will give you an idea? What was the chapter about?). c): No idea, haven't seen the term before

Comment: this is my lesson for topology course, this chapter about Links and Knots. I don't understand about this chapter.